# facebook login iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login

I have an app that I login to Facebook and get the public_profile then display first name and picture.
Like I said I got the picture working by using FBSDKProfilePictureView.

Now the only problem is that when I enter the view and I have previously logged in the picture and name appear.  I hit login button and the picture goes to silhouette and name goes to none.  hit login button again picture and name good.

However if I enter view when not logged in the name is none and the picture is silhouette ok.  I hit login button and I get 
Error: The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk.core error 8.)
the picture shows up but the name stays none
if i hit the login button to sign out the picture goes away and the name is the user first name and I get a log that there is no error from the sign in button..
hit login button to login and the picture is there and the name stays the first name and after that every thing works fine.
Here is my relevant code.

```
#import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h>
#import <FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginKit.h>
@interface videoUploadTestViewController () <FBSDKLoginButtonDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) FBSDKLoginButton *loginButton;
@property (strong, nonatomic) FBRequestConnection *requestConnection;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *labelFirstName;
@property (strong,nonatomic)IBOutlet FBSDKProfilePictureView *profilePictureView;
@property (strong,nonatomic) FBSDKLoginManager *loginManager;
- (IBAction)buttonRequestClickHandler:(id)sender;
@synthesize loginManager = _loginManager;
@synthesize loginButton = _loginButton;
@synthesize requestConnection = _requestConnection;
@synthesize labelFirstName = _labelFirstName;
- (void)dealloc {
    [_requestConnection cancel];
}

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
   NSLog(@"viewDidAppear");
   if ([_labelFirstName.text isEqualToString:@"none"]) {}
    else{
        self.loggedInString = @"logged in";
    }
    if ([loggedInString isEqualToString:@"logged in"]) {
        [_loginButton
         addTarget:self
         action:@selector(logoutButtonClicked) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    }
    else if ([loggedInString isEqualToString:@"logged out"]) {
        [_loginButton
         addTarget:self
         action:@selector(loginButtonClicked) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    }
    NSLog(@"loggedinstring:%@",loggedInString);
}


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSLog(@"viewDidLoad");
    _loginButton=[FBSDKLoginButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    _loginButton.backgroundColor=[UIColor darkGrayColor];
    _loginButton.frame=CGRectMake(0,150,180,28);
    [self.view addSubview:_loginButton];
   loggedInString = @"logged out";

//THIS IS WHERE I GET INFO IF ALREADY SIGNED IN
if ([FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]) {
        NSLog(@"currentAccessTokenviewDidLoad");
        [[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me" parameters:@{@"fields": @"id,first_name,picture.width(150).height(150)"}]
         startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
             if (!error) {
                 NSLog(@"fetched userviewdidload:%@", result);
                 NSString *helloString = NSLocalizedString(@"HELLO", nil);
                 NSString *userFirst = [helloString stringByAppendingString:[result objectForKey:@"first_name"] ];
                 self.labelFirstName.text = [userFirst stringByAppendingString:@"!"];

                 firstName =[result objectForKey:@"first_name"];

                 NSDictionary *dictionary = (NSDictionary *)result;

                 NSDictionary *data3 = [dictionary objectForKey:@"picture"];
                 NSDictionary *data2 = [data3 objectForKey:@"data"];
                 NSString *photoUrl = (NSString *)[data2 objectForKey:@"url"];

                 FBSDKProfilePictureView *profilePictureView = [[FBSDKProfilePictureView alloc] init];
                 profilePictureView = [dictionary objectForKey:@"picture"];
             }
         }];
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"firstNameviewDidLoad;%@",firstName);

        NSLog(@"noaccesstoken");


        self.labelFirstName.text = @"none";
    }


-(void)loginButtonClicked
{
     self.loggedInString = @"logged in";
    NSLog(@"loginclicked");
  /*_loginManager = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];*/
    [_loginManager
     logInWithReadPermissions: @[@"public_profile"]

     fromViewController:self
     handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {

         if (error) {
             NSLog(@"Process error");
         }
         else if (result.isCancelled) {
             NSLog(@"Cancelled");
         }
         else {
             NSLog(@"Logged in");
             if(result.token)   // This means if There is current access token.
             {
                 NSLog(@"token"); // Token created successfully and you are ready to get profile info

             }
         }
     }];

    if ([loggedInString isEqualToString:@"logged in"]) {
        [_loginButton
         addTarget:self
         action:@selector(logoutButtonClicked) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    }
    else if ([loggedInString isEqualToString:@"logged out"]) {
        [_loginButton
         addTarget:self
         action:@selector(loginButtonClicked) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    }


   NSLog(@"logintext2;%@",_loginButton.titleLabel.text);
    [self getFacebookProfileInfos];

}



-(void) logoutButtonClicked
{ self.loggedInString = @"logged out";

    NSLog(@"logoutclicked");

    self.labelFirstName.text = @"none";

    if ([loggedInString isEqualToString:@"logged in"]) {
        [_loginButton
         addTarget:self
         action:@selector(logoutButtonClicked) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    }
    else if ([loggedInString isEqualToString:@"logged out"]) {
        [_loginButton
         addTarget:self
         action:@selector(loginButtonClicked) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    }




    }
-(void)getFacebookProfileInfos {
    NSLog(@"firstName%@",firstName);
    if (firstName == NULL) {

        [[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me" parameters:@{@"fields": @"id,first_name,picture.width(150).height(150)"}]
         startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
             if (!error) {
// THIS IS WHAT SHOWS UP WHEN I CLICK SIGN OUT AFTER SIGNING IN FIRST TIME
                 NSLog(@"noerror");
                 firstName =[result objectForKey:@"first_name"];
                 NSString *helloString = NSLocalizedString(@"HELLO", nil);
                 NSString *userFirst = [helloString stringByAppendingString:firstName ];
                 self.labelFirstName.text = [userFirst stringByAppendingString:@"!"];

                              }
             else{
                 NSLog(@"firstnameerror:%@",firstName);
                             NSLog(@"Error: %@", error.localizedDescription);
                 [self.view setNeedsDisplay];
             }
         }];
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"currentAccessTokenprofileinfos");
    NSString *helloString = NSLocalizedString(@"HELLO", nil);
    NSString *userFirst = [helloString stringByAppendingString:firstName ];
    self.labelFirstName.text = [userFirst stringByAppendingString:@"!"];

    }

    }
```

I am really starting to get frustrated.  any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

This is a common problem when updating UI in response to a web service request.

In the closure that is called by FBSDK after the user logs in, it appears you're updating the UI (facebookImage, labelFirstName) on the same thread the web request was running on. This may not be (and usually is not) the "main thread" which has access to the UI.

Try dispatching those UI updates to the main thread. This will queue up the updates, and the next time the main thread is running it will perform your updates.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    self.labelFirstName.Text = // etc, etc;
});
```

Comment: Thx where would I put this. Will try it when I get home from work tonite

Comment: The way I'd approach it is to group all the lines that actually interact with UI elements together at the bottom of the if(!error) section and wrap the dispatch around them, letting the non-UI code run immediately on the current thread as it is now.

Comment: I tried this but it didn't help.  so I moved the NSLog(@"fetched userviewdidload:%@", result);

Comment: I tried this but it didn't help.  so I moved the NSLog(@"fetched userviewdidload:%@", result); outside the if(!error) and found that result was null.  so I put else {NSLog(@"Error: %@", error.localizedDescription);} and found Error: The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk.core error 8.)  I have changed my code in original post to have people see what is going on.  I created a FBSDKLoginManager and synthesized it so I don't alloc/init it so I don't get the window hierarchy error but still no updated name/image unless leave view reenter.

Comment: So I found I can use FBSDKProfilePictureView and the image comes and goes with the sign in and sign out.  I couldn't find anything for a label for FBLabel.  The wierd thing is that when i enter the view with no access token and assign _loginButton selector to loginButtonClicked it doesn't seem to be assigned.  but when I assign it in logoutButtonclicked it does.  Confused.